# Next.js Error: Invariant: page wasn't built

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I just ran into the following error when trying to build my project. Basically, everything works fine (seemingly) in development, but then the following happens: trying to build.

```
next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
   - Environments: .env

 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Collecting page data    
 ✓ Generating static pages (679/679)

> Build error occurred
Error: Invariant: page wasn't built
    at C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1727:47
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1724:84
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1343:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async build (C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:374:9)
    at async main (C:\dev\work\project\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next:155:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What I find strange is that when I try to redeploy a previous build that was working, I get the same error.

Checking the error log on Vercel then, the following error occurs on all pages being built;

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'auth' of 'e' as it is null.
    at u (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/601.js:1:14818)
    at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/601.js:1:15507)
    at s (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/601.js:1:10354)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/601.js:1:6250
    at Object.Kc [as useMemo] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:60:240)
    at exports.useMemo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/601.js:1:6166
    at Wc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:73:362)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
```

I am not really sure where to go from here; everything was working fine a few days ago even going back to an older working version gives these errors. The "Invariant: Page wasn't built" error isn't really helpful, and there is not much information about it on the internet. Does anyone have some pointers on what I can try? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error might be a result of passing a  **`<Link>`** without `href` or setting  `href` to an empty string, something like this `<Link href={value ?? ''}>...</Link>`

Comment: Thanks. I tried to just replace all the <Link components to <Link href="/"> but still got the same error, so I am unsure if that is the problem. When setting href to empty I usually get that error in the build log?

Comment: yeah, you might get this error on versel when you have i link with **null** or **undefined** href . you can check this bug in [github repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16107)

Comment: Yes, this seems to have been the issue - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This error "Error: Invariant: page wasn't built" come up when you created two pages with same possibilities of slug.
For Ex.

Page with slug: "/one/two"

from file: /pages/[...page].tsx file
and another page created from file: /pages/one/[slug].tsx

So for npm run dev, eventually both pages are accepted however at the time of page generation with npm run build, it generates the error of "Invariant: page wasn't built".

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/stackoverflow-test-2pppzr?file=%2Fpages%2F%5B...page%5D.tsx%3A6%2C27

Check the above sandbox code with :

```
file name: [...page].tsx
line no.: 6
code : page: ["OneNew", "two"]
```

If I keep page "One" then run dev will work but build will throw the same error. However, if I change it to "OneNew" then the build is generated successfully.

In your case, after your last build, some new dynamic pages are generated that have the same URL slug with a different file structure. so check the last created pages and you will get the issue for sure.

Comment: This was the problem for me. I had a static and a catch-all route, but the latter was returning the path of the static route in `getStaticPaths`.